# Find all complex numbers $z$ such that given quadratic has real solution

Tags: complex-numbers, quadratics

I have a question about this question. Find all complex numbers $z$ such that the equation
$$t^2 + [(z+\overline z)-i(z-\overline z)]t + 2z\overline z\ =\ 0$$
has a real solution $t$.

**Attempt at a solution**

The discriminant is

$[(z+\overline z) - i(z-\overline z)]^2 - 4(2z\overline z)$
$=\ (z+\overline z)^2 - 2i(z+\overline z)(z-\overline z) + [i(z-\overline z)]^2 -8z\overline z$
$=\ (z^2+2z\overline z+\overline z^2) -2i(z^2-\overline z^2) - (z^2-2z\overline z+\overline z^2)-8z\overline z$
$=\ -4z\overline z - 2iz^2 + 2i\overline z^2$

For real solutions, the discriminant must be non-negative. But $z$ is a complex number; how can complex numbers be positive or negative? This is what I don't understand.

Would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Your title needs improvement...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with $$z=x+iy$$ we get $$\bar z=x-iy$$ thus our equation is given by
$$t^2+2(x+y)t+2(x^2+y^2)=0$$
can you proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Just
set $z=u+iv$. The discriminant becomes
$$\Delta=4[(u+v)^2-2(u^2+v^2)]=-4(u-v)^2.$$
Hence the condition is $\;u=v,\;$  or $\;\arg z\equiv\dfrac\pi4\mod\pi$.

Comment: Why isn't the discriminant $4[(u+v)^2-2(u^2+v^2)]$?

Comment: @Vera: Just because I forgot to check my  computations… It's fixed now. Thanks for pointing it!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Letting $z=a+ib$ reduces the quadratic equation to one with only real coefficients.